# Detecting Collision and Reflecting the MovieClips in Flash AS2

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I'm working on a small game which involves two players. 
There are two Spaceships(MovieClips) and a ball. The problem i'm facing is that i want to reflect the two spaceships as soon as they collide(same with spaceship-ball collision).

Answer (score 0):

this question is too generic, you could use an existing physics engine (there's a lot of these) or make your own. for a simple hit-or-not approach, there is a native function calle hitTest. it will not help you in calculating how to bounce the things off though

here is a tutorial that helped me understand how to make a simple collision detection in the past http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html